# Start In Arguments For Executable DisplayFusion

Tags: windows, displayfusion

I have a shortcut with the start in arguments as `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` which works fine.  But I want to achieve the same effect when launching the application with a hotkey in display fusion.  Instead of writing a custom C# script to do it, I want to just use the application launcher.  I need to use the executable for the target application so I cannot set start in like I can with a shortcut.  What can I put into application parameters to achieve the same result?

Essentially what arguments can I pass to set start in on an executable?

Comment: Can't you create a shortcut and start that shortcut with Display Fusion?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work with shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to launch a shortcut by including the extension .lnk and set the start in parameters on the shortcut.